# Assembly-Info-NetCore task on Azure doesn't update the deps.json

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-devops

In our build pipeline, we added the following task:

```
  - task: Assembly-Info-NetCore@3
    inputs:
      Path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      FileNames: |
        **/*.csproj
      InsertAttributes: true
      IgnoreNetFrameworkProjects: true
      FileEncoding: 'auto'
      WriteBOM: false
      Company: 'Company'
      Copyright: 'Copyright © $(date:YYYY) Company'
      VersionNumber: ${{parameters.version}}.$(buildNumber)
      FileVersionNumber: ${{parameters.version}}.$(buildNumber)
      InformationalVersion: ${{parameters.version}}.$(buildNumber)
      PackageVersion: ${{parameters.version}}.$(buildNumber)
      LogLevel: 'verbose'
      FailOnWarning: true
      DisableTelemetry: false
```

It works nicely and all my files get the new version.

My issue is that that `***.deps.json` are not updated accordingly, if I take one of one my executable:

```
{
  "runtimeTarget": {
    "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0",
    "signature": ""
  },
  "compilationOptions": {},
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0": {
      "MyApp/7.2.0.16504": {
        "dependencies": {
          // Some third party DLL...
          "Some.Project": "1.0.0", //<-- Should be the version 7.2.0.16504 
          "Some.Other.Project": "1.0.0", //<-- Should be the version 7.2.0.16504 
          "Some.Another.Project": "1.0.0", //<-- Should be the version 7.2.0.16504 
        },
        "runtime": {
          "MyApp.dll": {}
        }
      },
      
      //...
      }
    }
}
```

And therefore, when I start my app, all those depends DLL are not loaded.
How can I update those `*.deps.json` files?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

Turns out the `dotnet restore` should be executed AFTER the `Assembly-Info-NetCore`.

I thought those `deps.json` were generated when doing the `dotnet build`, but it seems at least something is generated while doing the restore.